# Show fetched data after grouping in list in vue template

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm making timeline with users activities in vue template. I would like to list fetched data by grouping it by created_at.

I have fatched data with axios from laravel controller. Resulting array is bellow.

```
activities:Array[2]
    0:Object
        causer_id:1
        created_at:"2019-09-20 08:55:29"
        description:"updated"
        id:1
        subject_type:"App\User"
    1:Object
        causer_id:1
        created_at:"2019-10-20 08:58:10"
        description:"updated"
        id:2
        subject_type:"App\User"
```

How to group array by created_at, populate "timeline-day" with value, and then fill "timeline-box" with activities from that day?

```
<div class="timeline-day">
    ***created_at***
</div>
    <div class="timeline-box" >
        <div class="box-content" v-for="(activity, i) in activities" :key="i">
        <div class="box-item">{{ activity.subject_type }}</div>
        <div class="box-item">{{ activity.description }}</div>
        <div class="box-item">{{ activity.created_at }}</div>
   </div>
```

Comment: 1. Post whole code. 2. You want sort by created_at?

Comment: 2. I want to group by created_at, in tag "timeline_month" i want to show created_at and in tag "timeline-box" all activities for that date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do it.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data () {
    return {
      activities: [
        {
          causer_id: 1,
          created_at: "2019-09-20 08:55:29",
          description: "updated",
          id: 1,
          subject_type: "App\User"
        }, {
          causer_id: 1,
          created_at: "2019-09-20 09:54:25",
          description: "updated",
          id: 3,
          subject_type: "App\User"
        }, {
          causer_id: 1,
          created_at: "2019-10-20 08:58:10",
          description: "updated",
          id: 2,
          subject_type: "App\User"        
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  
  computed: {
    days () {
      const map = {}
      
      for (const activity of this.activities) {
        const day = activity.created_at.slice(0, 10)
        
        map[day] = map[day] || { created_at: day, activities: [] }
        map[day].activities.push(activity)
      }
      
      return Object.keys(map).sort().map(day => map[day])
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.timeline-day {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <template v-for="day in days">
    <div class="timeline-day">
      {{ day.created_at }}
    </div>
    <div class="timeline-box">
      <div class="box-content" v-for="(activity, i) in day.activities" :key="i">
        <div class="box-item">{{ activity.subject_type }}</div>
        <div class="box-item">{{ activity.description }}</div>
        <div class="box-item">{{ activity.created_at }}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>
</div>
```

It strips out the date using `activity.created_at.slice(0, 10)`.

For each day it builds up an object containing the date and the array of activities. These are all stored in `map`. Once it's finished it puts those objects in an array for use by the template.

While I have included a `sort()` for the dates it doesn't sort the activities, so in practice they would need to already be sorted. You could add in extra sorting if that assumption doesn't hold.

Sorting the activities first lends itself to a slightly different algorithm. The temporary `map` wouldn't be needed and the objects can just be held in the final array from the get go. As the activities are sorted the only object we need access to is the one at the end of the array. Either the next activity will be added to that last object or a new object needs creating.